# Bootstrap 3 Responsive menu items appear beside site logo not underneath

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Am relatively new to Bootstrap and have run into this unusual problem - when I shrink down my window to test for responsiveness and click the toggle menu the menu opens beside the site name (Greg in this case).

I have a feeling I need to wrap some of the navigation in a different or additional tags to get it to appear properly. Would love your help.

My current code is:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Greg</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
            <div class="menu-flobble-container">
                <ul id="menu-flobble" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li id="menu-item-77"
                        class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-77">
                        <a title="contact" href="http://datapups.com/contact/">contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-78"
                        class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-78">
                        <a title="portfolio" href="http://datapups.com/portfolio/">portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-79"
                        class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-79">
                        <a title="privacy" href="http://datapups.com/privacy/">privacy</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-86"
                        class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-86 dropdown">
                        <a title="Dairy" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"
                        class="dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true">Dairy
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                        <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
                            <li id="menu-item-88"
                                class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-88">
                                <a title="Cheese" href="http://datapups.com/cheese/">Cheese</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-87"
                        class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-87">
                        <a title="Nuts" href="http://datapups.com/nuts/"> Nuts</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Wow I didn't realise this was so hard to resolve - will look elsewhere for help. Thanks for looking anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add in the bootstrap row and col divs to make sure it becomes underneath it.

```
<div class = "container">
  <div class="row>
     <div class="col-md-12">

        <a href = "#" class = "navbar-brand">Greg</a>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
          rest of nav
      </div>
</div>
```